# TypeScript static members vs namespace with class name

Tags: class, typescript, module, namespaces

In TypeScript, I have been separating non-instance variables out of my classes and into a namespace with the same name as the class. For example:

```
class Person
{
    age: number;

    constructor(age: number)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

namespace Person
{
    export let numberOfFingers: number = 10;
}

export default Person;
```

as opposed to this:

```
class Person
{
    static numberOfFingers: number = 10;

    age: number;

    constructor(age: number)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

export default Person;
```

Is there any benefit to either of these methods?

Answer (score 2):

As far as typechecking and code generation is concerned, both methods produce exactly the same results. I can offer two not very strong arguments in favor of static members:

- it's the most obvious thing to do, it does not require knowledge of advanced parts of the language ([declaration merging](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Declaration%20Merging.md)) to understand the code
- if you ever need to have a function that creates and returns class definition ([as described for example here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17829#issuecomment-323020591), to simulate static generic member or to add a mixin), then namespaces will not work - you can't have namespace inside a function.